# Eclipse - configure nexus repositroy

Tags: eclipse, nexus

Can someone help how should i configure Nexus remote repository into my eclipse.

Is it possible to configure nexus remote URL ? or not , i am  not sure.
If someone has any idea please share me.

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct way of entering Nexus URLs in Eclipse

You have to modify the repostiory URLs through Maven settings.xml.

If you are using Maven eclipse plugin. Location of settings file can be found from Maven->User Settings preference.

More details can be found here https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: With "Maven eclipse plugin" you mean m2e.